# Vertical Div Spacing

Tags: css, html, spacing

How do you horizontally distribute 3 divs with the least amount of code?

I have 3 divs that have the same class, and I need to distribute them horizontally, with 19 pixels of space between each div.

My solution currently is to give the first 2 divs a right margin of 19 pixels, and assign a separate class to the 3rd div that gives it a left margin of 19 pixels.

This gets the job done, but I feel like there may be a better way of doing it. Ideally, all 3 divs would still have the same class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/q6Hj8/

```
.yourDivClass + .yourDivClass {
    margin-left: 19px
}
```

That uses the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) to apply `margin-left` to every `.yourDivClass` which is preceded by a `.yourDivClass` - in other words, all except the first.

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. This is the first time I've ran into css selectors. Any compatibility/support issues across browsers?

Comment: You're welcome. `+` works everywhere, *except* for the ancient IE6 (which you should no longer care about).

Answer (score 1):

You only need two columns with a right margin; the third column needs no additional margin.  Border added so you can see it in a fiddle.

```
div.hasMargin
{
    margin-right: 19px;
}

div.column
{
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/jkLAK/)

Comment: I think @thirtydot nailed it with simplicity.

Comment: If you wanted to use this (the only reason to would be IE6 support), you'd be better adding inverting it and adding a single `noMargin` class instead of multiple `hasMargin` classes: http://jsfiddle.net/jkLAK/1/