# What does it mean to + the same style with itself?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know, that makes no sense. Take a look here and you'll see what I mean

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/q6Hj8

The part where it is

```
.yourDivClass + .yourDivClass {....
```

It seems to eliminate the enclosed style to the end Div. Is it a common way of achieving that effect?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html see 5.7

Comment: @danontheline: seems like an answer to me. Answer's the question perfectly

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's css style "p + p"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/whats-css-style-p-p)

Comment: For more informations about CSS selectors, check this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @Oltarus good and bad link here. The list is easier to read and access when you just need to remember something. Often W3Schools is not up-to-date though and has false information, see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: I thought I explained it adequately in the first place: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7080035/405015 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per section [5.7: Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) of the the W3C CSS Specification: (formatting for clarity)

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where
> E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if
>
> 1. E1 and E2
>    share the same parent in the document tree and
> 2. E1 immediately precedes
>    E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).
>
> **Thus, the following rule states that when a P element immediately
> follows a MATH element, it should not be indented:**
>
> ```
> math + p { text-indent: 0 }
> ```

It basically means when the **second** element is in the same context AND follows the **first** element in the code directly (without any other elements in between), the following attribute will be added to the **second** element!

In your jsfiddle example it means that the 'margin-left' will be applied to the *whole/both class/es* (because both selectors are the same in your example) **only if** the element is following itself in your code, which it does. Try

```
<div class="Yourclass">
<div class="cloneofyourclass">
<div class="Yourclass">
```

and no additional `margin-left` from your example will be applied.

*Note that Internet Explorer 6 will **not** accept any of those selectors! IE7 and higher will do though!*

Answer (score 1):

It means you're looking for a `.yourDivClass` which is a sibling directly after another `.yourDivClass`.

Comment: Nope, only `.yourDivClass` sibilings that come **just after** another `.yourDivClass`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Adjacent Sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) has fairly good support among modern browsers.  It's great for styling certain things, like the first paragraph after a header or the second of two ordered lists, etc.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.